# Moving a button Up in navigation bar not working IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a button in navigation bar. I am trying to move the text little bit up so that I can add one more text downside, However its not working, text is always in the middle irrespective of my rect position. Is it possible to move a button up or down in navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want move button title you can use it.

```
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];
```